# java.lang.NullPointerException: parentLoader == null && !nullAllowed

Tags: android, ehcache

I am trying to use ehcache in my android app. It fails on the first line. So this isn't anything to do with a bad cache configuration. I am planning to configure cache programatically so I do not have any config files. All I did was add ehcache as a dependency and try calling the method below. Using ehcache 2.10.2

```
        CacheManager singletonManager = CacheManager.create();
```

Stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-158
Process: test.app, PID: 7275
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:208)
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:152)
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:103)
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:140)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:892)
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:873)
at test.app.MyCache.setup(MyCache.java:20)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: parentLoader == null && !nullAllowed
at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:210)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:202)
at net.sf.ehcache.EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.<init>(EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.java:35)
at net.sf.ehcache.EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.<clinit>(EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.java:26)
at net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:208) 
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:152) 
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:103) 
at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:140) 
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:892) 
at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:873) 
at test.app.MyCache.setup(MyCache.java:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CacheManager singletonManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
```

Not: `create()`

**EDIT:**

You're right. Still the same problem. I tried it

```
Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
```

This means there was no SLF4J binding.

> Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem

Here's the **[link](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)**.
make sure you only add ONE jar

**EDIT 2**:

if you want to remove the config warning, add ehcache.xml file. Here's an exmaple:

```
<defaultCache
    maxElementsInMemory="10000"
    eternal="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="120"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120"
    overflowToDisk="true"
    maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
    diskPersistent="false"
    diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
/>
```

Try it out.

Comment: same problem. Upon inspecting, getInstance just calls create

Comment: Check my edited answer. I tried it. it fixes the problem

Comment: That does not fix the problem for me, although the SLF4J configuration error went away.  I see this in the log but I don't think I need to be concerned: System.err: [main] WARN net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory - No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath: jar:file:/data/app/test.app-2/base.apk!/ehcache-failsafe.xml

Comment: that's just warning saying it's using the `ehcache-failsafe.xml` which is a backup if config file is not there. Config file missing is not an error. You are not required to have this config file. is there anything else printing? Also, see the edit in my answer to add the config file

Comment: no the same stacktrace. it works for you in android? Yes the xml  config prevents the warning but stacktrace remains.

Comment: Can I see what you're doing in your `main` before creating `singletonManager`? update your question if you can. It would be nice to see the entire thing.

Comment: It is very simple, nothing special. Interesting that ehcache 3.0.0 works for me